# Can not modify tab indicator color

Tags: css, angular, materialize

I am using materializecss with Angular 6. I am not using ng2-materilize, just the materializecss library.

The problem is when I try to change the tab indicator background color modifying the css of the component. I algo use !important but it is the same.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
  <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width" id="chartstabs">
    <li class="tab" *ngFor="let view of views">
      <a href="#tab{{view.id}}" (click)="loadTab(view)">{{view.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this is my css.

```
.tabs {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.tabs .indicator {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no class *indicator* in your HTML

Comment: yes, this is because it is an element added by the materilizecss library.

Comment: See if it's being overwritten by a more powerful selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use `/deep/` to overwrite the existing styles

```
/deep/ .tabs {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
/deep/ .tabs .indicator {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: actually this >>> or /deep/ will be removed in further versions of angular. I think it is not a definitive solution.

Comment: That's right in future all the styling changes must be done through theme configuration.

Answer (score 4):

its changing the color. i'm just using tabs without `angularjs`

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.tabs').tabs();
  });
```

```css
 .tabs {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
.tabs .indicator {
    background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div class="row">
<div class="col s12 m12 l12 xl12">
  <!-- <ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width" id="chartstabs">
    <li class="tab">
      <a href="#tab" (click)="loadTab(view)">okkk</a>
    </li>
  </ul> -->
  
  
<ul class="tabs tabs-fixed-width tab-demo z-depth-1" id="chartstabs">
    <li class="tab"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>
    <li class="tab disabled"><a href="#test3">Disabled Tab</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    <li class="tab"><a href="#test0">Test 5</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12"><p>Test 1</p></div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12"><p>Test 2</p></div>
  <div id="test3" class="col s12"><p>Test 3</p></div>
  <div id="test4" class="col s12"><p>Test 4</p></div>
  <div id="test0" class="col s12"><p>Test 5</p></div>
  
  
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer but I still not working. I think it is because angular 6 but I can not be sure.

Comment: can you create a fiddle with angular?

Answer (score 2):

I liked the @Sunil Singh answer, but you're right, those selectors are deprecated, so here's my workaround:

Just put the css rules in a root styles.css attached to index.html, so there indicator will be affected. If you want to control the specific page for that rule, you can use ids in each tabs component.